# Sharepoint 2007 search webservice XML error

Tags: web-services, soap, sharepoint-2007

I am getting the dreaded "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." error from the Sharepoint spsearch SOAP webservice.
I get this error when using the Eclipse web service explorer and also when I use the http://localhost/_vti_bin/spsearch.asmx?op=Query help page "Test" function on the Sharepoint server.
The Sharepoint installation has no _vti_cnf directories which I understand can cause this error.  Where else should I look?

A related problem is that another installation of Sharepoint is displaying

"The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters." 
on its Query help test form. Clearly the required string parameter *is* of a primitive type.

Thanks,
Andy